# This show something else where adding to prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I try to add to prototype new function but when I try to call this.foo() it says that foo not exist but foo() exists in fact.

```
 Date.prototype.getWeek = function() {
    var onejan = new Date(this.getFullYear(),0,1);
    return Math.ceil((((this - onejan) / 86400000) + onejan.getDay()+1)/7);
 }
```

I get error that getFullYear is not a function. How to workaround this?

Comment: Where is the `foo()`? Looks like your [code works](http://jsfiddle.net/a9Dkc/) as it is.

Comment: Like [Teemu](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1169519) said, it should work. But keep in mind that it is not the best idea to extend build-in types with own functions. E.g. what would happen if future implementations would add `getWeek`? Would they start the weeks with `0` or with `1`?

Comment: I want to use in jira. And there is many imports other scripts, so "this" shows some thinks else. I want to have something which will be replenishment of java/c++ "this".

Comment: @t.niese According to [ISO standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date), the first week of an year can be 52, 53 or 1, but never 0 ; ).

Comment: @Teemu Yes it is likely that it starts with `1`. But if you would imagine, that `getDay`  would not exist and the OP would implement `Date.prototype.getDay` you would not know if the week would start with `Su` or `Mo` and if the numeric value starts with `0` or `1`. Or `getMonth` that starts with `0`. I just want to make clear that there is a risk in extending buld-in types.

Comment: @t.niese Yes ofcourse, I agree with you with this, usually it's better to not fork native prototypes.